# What are the popular free online magazines on Hinduism?

Tags: resource

Can anybody suggest any popular online magazine on Hinduism? If possible, please suggest more than one.

Comment: https://ebooks.tirumala.org/search.php?key=author&value=sapthagiri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hinduism Today magazine** is a very good magazine about Hinduism. The issues are even avaliable for [**download in PDF**](https://www.hinduismtoday.com/magazine-downloads/) versions. Hinduism Today magazine is a global public service to the family of Hindu faiths, produced by a small monastic community based in Hawaii.

Hinduism Today was founded January 5, 1979, by Satguru Sivaya Subramuniyaswami. It is a nonprofit educational activity of Himalayan Academy.
Their website lists their  purposes as :

1 To foster Hindu solidarity as a unity in diversity among all sects and lineages
 2 To inform and inspire Hindus worldwide and people interested in Hinduism 
3 To dispel myths, illusions and misinformation about Hinduism 
4 To protect, preserve and promote the sacred Vedas and the Hindu religion
5. To nurture and monitor the ongoing spiritual Hindu renaissance;
6. To publish a resource for Hindu leaders and educators who promote Sanatana Dharma.

To those who are intrested there are also various articles about Hinduism   to read on the web site. Here is the link to [**Hinduism Today**](https://www.hinduismtoday.com/) main Web Site.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Probably this magazine is the best!

Comment: Yes , their are lot's of small publications in India which publish magazines in their local languages region wise but their reach is limited to their respective sect. This is the one which is in English and cover more comprehensive topics  than those. We will try to find some more meantime.

Comment: Which sampradaya Satguru Sivaya Subramuniyaswami ji hails from?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - Satguru Sivaya Subramuniyaswami
belongs to Nandinatha Sampradaya's Kailasa Parampara (
Tamil Saivite tradition) also known  as Saiva Siddhanta Church.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Do they follow Sanyasism?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto- Yeah , there are nearly    two dozen monks residing in Kauai  monastery temple complex in Hawaii.

Answer (score 4):

Hinduism Today is the best, I guess. Here I have found a few additional magazines, which might also be useful.

1. [Prabuddha Bharata](https://advaitaashrama.org/read/) (monthly magazine): It is a publication from Ramkrishna Math. It is mostly on Advaita Vedanta. PDFs are downloadable for free.
2. [Pragyata](https://pragyata.com) - You can read the articles online for free.

Comment: That's interesting list and certainly will be helpful to readers.

Comment: Mountain path from 1964.  Published by Ramana Ashram. PDFs are downloadable for free. It is mostly on Advaita Vedanta. https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/resource_centre/publications/mountain-path/